# How to prove default max heap limit of v8 in nodejs ，Or if method "process.memoryUsage()" exactly show the total heap?

Tags: node.js, memory, v8

I read one book,It says the default max old generation of v8 is 1.4G in x64 ,
Use method "process.memoryUsage()" to show the memory usage,
The author prove it by some code,repeat push Array object to a global var.
After several times ,out of memory occurred.
When I wrote some code different,repeat write some strings to a file,
The limit quickly broken.So what's diffrent between our code on memory usage? 
Is the method "process.memoryUsage()" truely shows the memory usage?
(My OS windows x64,16G memory,node 8,node options are default)
Any help will be thankful!!!

Here is the author's code :

```
outofmemory.js

var showMem = function (times) {
    var mem = process.memoryUsage();
    var format = function (bytes) {
        return (bytes / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
    };
    console.log('Process: heapTotal ' + format(mem.heapTotal) +
        ' heapUsed ' + format(mem.heapUsed) + ' rss ' + format(mem.rss));
    console.log(`--------------------------${times}---------------------------------`);
};

var useMem = function () {
    var size =  20*1024 * 1024;
    var arr = new Array(size);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
    return arr;
};
var total = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    showMem(j);
    total.push(useMem());
}
showMem();
```

The out put

```
...
Process: heapTotal 1286.92 MB heapUsed 1284.28 MB rss 1301.80 MB
--------------------------8---------------------------------

<--- Last few GCs --->

[15468:00000267A6225110]     1074 ms: Mark-sweep 1284.0 (1290.9) -> 1283.9 (1290.9) MB, 119.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[15468:00000267A6225110]     1195 ms: Mark-sweep 1283.9 (1290.9) -> 1283.9 (1287.9) MB, 120.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[15468:00000267A6225110]     1314 ms: Mark-sweep 1283.9 (1287.9) -> 1283.9 (1287.9) MB, 118.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested

...
```

Here is mine:

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function writeFile(){
    const fd =  fs.openSync('a.log', 'a');
    const log = async (entry) =>{
        await fs.writeSync(fd, entry+'\r\n', null, 'utf8');
        await fs.fsyncSync(fd);
    }

    for(let t = 0; t<10000 ; t++ ) {
        for(var i = 0x4E00;i<=0x9FBF;++i)
            log(String.fromCharCode(i));
        showMem({times:t});
    }
}

const showMem = function ({times}) {
    const mem = process.memoryUsage();
    const format = function (bytes) {
        return (bytes / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
    };

    console.log('Process: heapTotal ' + format(mem.heapTotal) +
        ' heapUsed ' + format(mem.heapUsed) + ' rss ' + format(mem.rss));
    console.log(`-----------------------------${times}--------------------------------\r\n`)
}
writeFile();
```

The out put:

```
...
Process: heapTotal 2733.34 MB heapUsed 2655.47 MB rss 2756.39 MB
-----------------------------199--------------------------------


<--- Last few GCs --->

[24568:000001E7950D8B40]   380916 ms: Mark-sweep 2660.1 (2748.3) -> 2660.0 (2748.8) MB, 2900.9 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[24568:000001E7950D8B40]   383390 ms: Mark-sweep 2660.0 (2748.8) -> 2660.0 (2715.3) MB, 2473.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[24568:000001E7950D8B40]   385803 ms: Mark-sweep 2660.0 (2715.3) -> 2660.0 (2712.3) MB, 2411.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I got it by myself

The printed "heapTotal,heapUsed" include both old generation and new generation,Both of them can be set by node options:

```
(CentOS 7.3 x64 4G)

 node --max-old-space-size=100  --max_semi_space_size=100  wf.js
```